# how to Zip 2 lists with different sizes and display all elements inside lazy column?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The current problem

```
val todayRoute = selectRouteViewModel.TodayRoute.collectAsState().value. // 6 elements
val collected = listOf(CompletedRoute(id = 31, name = "Oxfam", completed = 1, arrived = 1)) // 1 element

val route = todayRoute.selectRoute.zip(collected)

val ids = route.first.id + " " + route.second.id
 
print(ids) // 21 31
```

todayRoute has 6 elements, collected has 1 element

I want to show all elements in todayRoute regardless of list size

Comment: can you provide example of what you want

Comment: @i30mb1 I've updated it. todayRoute has 6 elements, collected has 1 element

I want to show all elements in todayRoute regardless of list size

Answer (score 0):

zip, by default, the your route collection contains Pairs of source collection elements with the same index. The size of your route collection equals the minimum size of your resource collections.
So the size of the route collection will be 1 and will ignore the remaining 5 values ​​while zipping.

[image for zip logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZBK9.png)

If you want to get all 7 items, I can suggest you to create a new collection and add it there.